# Problemas com impressão de background usando bootstrap no Firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, impressão, firefox

Boa tarde amigos,

Não tenho muita prática com Bootstrap ainda, não consegui descobrir uma maneira de manter o background de uma div, quando faço a impressão de uma página pelo window.print()

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="qCor" style="background-color: #752740 !important;">
```

Em tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ao imprimir pelo navegador o background da div fica em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão como posso desviar esse problema?

Comment: Utilize também essa propriedade no seu _style_: `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`

Comment: Para o Chrome funcionou 100%. Mas precisaria para o Firefox, conhece alguma alternativa para Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiz uns testes aqui no chrome e vi que imprime sem os backgrounds quando a opção `background graphics` está desabilitada.

Ela fica na tela que você vai confirmar a impressão, escolher impressora ou PDF, etc.
clica em `Mais configurações` vai ser a última opção (no meu browser está `background graphics`).

fazendo via CSS: voce nao conseguira atingir todos os browsers

```
.suaClasse{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /*funciona no chrome e opera*/
    color-adjust: exact; /*funciona no Firefox*/
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá André, a alternativa que o Douglas comentou, funciona no Chrome, porém preciso uma alternativa para o Firefox.

Comment: eu tentei o que ele comentou aqui e pra mim não tinha funcionado, por isso nem citei

Comment: Testei assim no Chrome style=" -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; background-color: #752740  !important;" e funcionou!

Comment: vi aqui e só funciona para o chrome e safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

Comment: atualizei a resposta, serve pro firefox `color-adjust: exact;`

Comment: Encontrei uma maneira, usando o  "color-adjust: exact !important;", começou a funcionar no Firefox.

Comment: Isso ai. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Opa, encontrei uma solução.

Modifiquei o style seguindo sugestão do Douglas.

```
style=" -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; color-adjust: exact !important; background-color: #752740  !important;"
```

Desse modo está funcionando tanto no Chrome quanto no Firefox.

Obrigado pelos comentários.